# Front crawl training

Tags: technique, training, swimming, performance

I am a hobby swimmer. I train each day, swimming front crawl with the following regime:

- 500 meters using just my legs
- 500 meters using just my arms
- 500 meters using both legs and arms.

It takes me about 1h to complete this. I have noticed that I go significantly slower when I use just my legs. Is this normal, or is my technique/legs to blame?

Also, how does my training regimen compare to that of a professional swimmer? I suspect that 1500 meters/day is very little, but I am not sure...

Comment: I cannot comment on the first question, but I think the answer to the second question (whether or not 1500 m/day is enough or not) depends a lot on what your goals with your training are.

Comment: Not sure why this has a close vote for "off topic," but the question is legit in regards to how swimming technique may affect performance and calls on the expertise of a swimmer in regards to training regimen.

Comment: You might have more success editing out your last paragraph and making that a question on its own. I'm not a swimmer, but I imagine the volume of training required to reach certain goals would be something more people are likely to have useful information about than information about the quiet specific technique the first part of your question asks.

Answer (score 2):

I am too a hobby swimmer but as part of my triathlon training. I swim with a club where the ability range is from *beginner* up to one guy who swam at the *Olympics*.

Without exception all are slower over the same distance when using only legs. So from that survey I would say that you are quite normal.

As with all three triathlon disciplines the quantity of training will not necessarily make you a better athlete. You must include sprints, pyramids, fartleks and other forms of technique training in order to improve.

At my club our best triathlete can complete an Ironman in under 9 hours - so that's a *3.8km* swim in less than an hour followed by a *180k* bike ride at an average of *39 km/h* and then run a sub *3 hour* marathon.

To achieve that he trains on average *12 hours per week*. Not as much as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

1500m a day seems a very short distance. My ten year old swims 3500 to 4000m each evening as part of her training.

When I was competing in inter-county swimming races in my late teens, I would swim about 5k each evening, and another 1500m each morning. And while I was pretty fast in my county,  I was never going to be up at the speed professionals swim

At risk of stating the obvious, when you use arms and legs you go much faster than arms or legs alone. This is perfectly normal.